# Contact lookup shows not result on screen flow on Community

Tags: lookup, customer-community, screen-flow

I have created a screen flow to be used on the community website but the contact lookup field is not working. I tried all available suggestions on google and still no luck.
[image]

Comment: What were you expecting? What did you obtain instead?

Comment: You can't use `MasterRecordId` field since this is controlled by the system.  It is only used for merged contact purposes. You need to use your own custom lookup field in the Field API Name field.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what is your issue here. But looking at the values you used I think you may have to look at the documentation first ([Flow Screen Input Component: Lookup](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_lookup.htm)).

Field API Name is the API name of a lookup field on the source object. Are you sure you're using `MasterRecordId` as value?

---

Here an explanation of the four most important fields.

| Field | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| API Name | API name that you're assigning to the Lookup component. |
| Field API Name | The API name of a lookup field on the source object. |
| Label | Label that will be used in the flow screen. Unless you know what you're doing, I suggest using the same label used in the system for the field selected in Field API Name. |
| Object API Name | The API name of the source object. |

Without knowing more about your data model or what you want to achieve is impossible to help you more than this.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
I am trying to search for Contact records via the screen flow. I tried to reference the public Contact object but I had no luck. I saw an article that mentioned using the method in my picture. I am open to all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used the permission "Portal Super User" to grant customer portal users edit access to the Case object via Flow screen